# apache 2.4 give "httpd -k start", status shows "Active: inactive (dead)"

Tags: apache, fedora-23

I'm using Fedora release 23 (Twenty Three) and Apache/2.4.23 (Fedora)

I notice that apache 2.4 has -DFOREGROUND as default when starting:

```
/usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

I don't want the -DFOREGROUND, for apache 2.2 that I previously used, it has

```
/usr/sbin/httpd -k start
```

and thats what I want. so I modified the httpd.service:

```
# ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND  # default in apache 2.4
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -k start        # this is what I want and in the previous machine that has apache 2.2
```

but after the change, after "systemctl daemon-reload" and "service httpd start", the httpd status shows inactive (dead):

```
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2017-03-06 10:18:37 CST; 1min 20s ago
 Main PID: 4464 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Status: "Total requests: 89051; Idle/Busy workers 75/25;Requests/sec: 0.279; Bytes served/sec: 4.1KB/sec"

Mar 02 17:48:19 GAFServer systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Mar 02 17:48:19 GAFServer httpd[4464]: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::fe4d:d4ff:fef1:e121. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Mar 02 17:48:19 GAFServer systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Mar 06 03:32:01 GAFServer httpd[23093]: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::fe4d:d4ff:fef1:e121. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Mar 06 03:32:01 GAFServer systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
Mar 06 10:18:35 GAFServer systemd[1]: Stopping The Apache HTTP Server...
Mar 06 10:18:37 GAFServer systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
```

I'm so confused, apache document has so little about what is DFOREGROUND and what other options I have, how can I stop using this DFOREGROUND?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `FOREGROUND` is a Fedora customisation. You can use `-D` to *define a name for use in `<IfDefine name>` directives*. Why exactly do you want to get rid of it?

Comment: Ah, thanks for reply. I'm new to apache, can I just make the httpd status looks like "/usr/sbin/httpd -k start"? I don't want have any -D options, I just want my server behaves the same as before.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not a Fedora user. But if that's how Fedora service handling works, you'll possibly have to live with it or switch to another distro. If you fiddle with the system internals you'll just break stuff. Being familiar with stuff is a luxury you can't have when you work in IT.

Comment: from what I learn these days, DFOREGROUND will force process spawned by apache running in foreground, I have some ajax call that starts very long task, and I want this long task to run in background and have an instant ajax return says "your task has been started", so I need to use any options other than DFOREGROUND right?

Comment: hmm, ok... I'll look into the IfDefine, thanks for your help :)

Comment: Just don't forget I know nothing about Fedora, I only thought that *why* you need that was a relevant piece of information.